# MySql, Monitor database for table changes and inform other

Tags: mysql, windows

I have been asked to create a daemon app that will poll a mysql database for table updates and update another database accordingly. The two databases are completely different but there is a table that it has to be in sync between them. If it was up to me I wouldn't have designed it that way.

I thought that instead of polling MySql every 5 minutes, I could setup MySql in a way that it notifies my daemon application or (maybe) sends an http request to a web server every time a table update is issued.

Is this possible?

PS. MySql is setup in a PHP/Windows environment.